# Polybase doesn't create external file format

Tags: sql-server, azure-virtual-machine, polybase, sql-server-2019

I get the good old

> Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'.

error. I am exactly doing what [this answer describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603542/how-to-make-a-file-format-in-sql-server/52961148#52961148). But SQL Server returns the aforementioned error when I come to this code-chunk:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT csvformat 
WITH ( 
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, 
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR =',') 
);
GO
```

What am I doing wrong?

**What I tried**

- Java runtime environment is installed (Java 8 Update 201)
- PolyBase is installed with "PolyBase Query Service for External Data"
- I enabled PolyBase with `EXEC sp_configure 'hadoop connectivity', 4;`. I also set that option to `1` and `7` - I still get that error
- Using `EXEC sp_configure`, I also set `'polybase enabled'` to `1`
- I checked `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('IsPolybaseInstalled') AS IsPolybaseInstalled;` - it returns `1`
- My TCP is enabled
- My PolyBase is running:

[image]
Setup: SQL Server 2019 on a Virtual Machine (Azure), no Azure SQL Server or Azure DWH.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your installation, but the problem lies there.  You _will_ get that syntax error until you install PolyBase.

Comment: Thanks that at least gives a direction. Is there any elaborate guide line how to install PolyBase? I remember the Microsoft Docs being quite brief

Comment: I just added the feature to my existing SQL 2017 install, and other than the Java prerequites, I just clicked through the installer.

Comment: Same here. I will try with SQL Server 2017 then. That way I can rule out that there is some issue in my 2019 Installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps too simple answer, but can you restart entire virtual server and try it again?

---

**Update:** Reboot of the server/service after installation of Polybase is not stated in the documentation, also not requested by the installer, however plenty of messages on user boards tell that it is required to make Polybase work.

Comment: embarrasingly enough that worked for me. Odd since the VM restarted after the installation of PolyBase.